# LSTM for classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, lstm, keras

I have a dataset which consists of $n_\text{samples}$ different measurements. Each measurement contains $n_\text{features}$ features. These features are for example `average_mass`, `average_charge`, `speed`, `position_x`, `position_y`, ...

In addition, each measurement was done at a certain time $t$ which is also known. I want to classify the measurements into $C$ classes. For this, I obtained a training set with labels $i \in \lbrace1,2,3,\ldots, C\rbrace$. Therefore, this can be treated as a supervised learning task. Lets say all $n_\text{samples}$ are labeled and the classifier should be able to work on new unseen data.

One could think now of different methods to do build such a classifier:

1. Treat each of the $n_\text{samples}$ measurements independently and show them to the classifier. E.g. one could build a RandomForest with the above mentioned features and estimate its performance by using cross validation. This ansatz would completely ignore the time informaion.
2. Use a classifier which makes explicit use of the time information. E.g. one could reshape the feature matrix of shape `[n_samples, n_features]` into a 3D tensor of shape `[n_samples', n_timesteps, n_features]` where `n_timesteps` is the number of consecutive timesteps which are considered as one sequence. `n_samples'` is now smaller than `n_samples`, since the orginal `n_samples` are grouped together in sequences of length `n_timesteps`.

To fix some numbers, lets say there are $C=10$ classes, $n_\text{samples}=10^5$, $n_\text{timesteps}=4$, $n_\text{features}=20$ .

For the second method, I used an LSTM. The keras code for the model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(64,
                       input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features),
                       return_sequences=True,
                       stateful=False))
        model.add(LSTM(32,
                       return_sequences=True,
                       stateful=False))
        model.add(LSTM(32,
                       return_sequences=False,
                       stateful=False))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(num_classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))
        model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=self.loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It turned out that a RandomForest trained with approach 1 (i.e. ignore the time) works way better than the LSTM. I find this astounding as I assumed that since there is a correlation between the measurements in the time direction (position and speed at time 1 will certainly affect the position at time 2), a method which uses the time domain will outperform a classifier which ignores this extra information.

Now I have the following questions:

1. Most often LSTMs are used for time series prediction or seq2seq tasks (eg. text translations or speech recognition). Hence I wonder if an LSTM is even a good choice for my problem?
2. Is my network design suitable or are there better ways to construct a LSTM network for my task?
3. What are other alternatives, which make use of the temporal correlations? Different network types?

Comment: Even though RF outperforms the other approach, it is not correct to ignore  lack of sample independence (mass and position at time 2 are certainly dependent on the value of those parameters at time 1). I do not know much about LSTM to give a full answer.